# NetBeans and GWT Fast edit/refresh in Development mode

Tags: gwt, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans with the GWT plugin. Unlike Eclipse, I'm required to `build` everytime I want to reflect a change in my browser.

Is there a way to eliminate this step in NetBeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [Gwt4nb](http://github.com/ksfreitas/gwt4nb) plugin? It allows you to do Development Mode when you are debugging your project. Then when you change your GWT code, just refresh your browser window and you will see changes.

I'm using NetBeans for almost 3 years already with GWT and never had problems with that plugin, never needed to got to Eclipse.